# Sharepoint Site master page not applied using designer

Tags: 2013, master-page, design-manager

I have converted my HTML to masterpage and published a major version of it.
When applying master page using design master page, I change the site master page to my newly converted masterpage and the system master page to seattle.

However the master page does not get applied to site. When changing the system mp to custom mp the mp gets applied. This also changes the layout of the admin pages(like site settings, contents,etc).

I do not want to apply my master page to site admin pages. Kindly help!

Comment: Hi @user67615, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :) Regarding your issue, you said In case you set site and system master page to custom it's worked! , could u try now to switch back the system master page to oslo and check if it's worked or not?

Comment: on changing system to oslo/seattle, the whole site layout changes to that.

Comment: please add some of the screenshot to can help you faster :)

Comment: screenshots of what?...
site mp: custom
system mp : oslo
result: the entire site inculding pages, lists,lib,admin pages all become oslo.

site mp:custom
system mp :custom

Comment: okay, it's clear now, it's the root site, right ?

Comment: yes its the root site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction between the **system** master page (aka "default master page" in SharePoint Designer, aka `MasterUrl` in the C# API) and the **site** master page (aka "custom master page" in SharePoint Designer, aka `CustomMasterUrl` in the C# API) only appears for **publishing** sites.

In a *team site*, only the system master page is taken into account for both the site pages (i.e. the wiki pages relying in the `SitePages` doc lib) and the "admin" pages (the ones in the *_layouts* virtual folder).

In a *publishing* site, publishing pages (the ones from the `Pages` library) do use the site master page. All other pages (wiki pages, if any, and *_layouts* pages) still use the system MP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So that means mine is a team site. I created a publishing subsite, and applied mp there. Works perfect there.
How do i change my root site to publishing site?

Comment: To turn a Team Site to a Publishing site, you simply need to activate 2 features: the Publishing Infrastructure at the site collection level + the Publishing feature at the site (may be the root) level + at any other sub-site level you want. See e.g. http://sharepointmaven.com/activate-publishing-features-in-sharepoint/ for more info. Nota that, after that, only new (publishing) pages will use the site master page; existing wiki pages created previously are still "team site pages" and thus still use the system MP only. Also note that I don't recommend reverting back to a simple team site...